# Python Reg-Ex find File Name

Tags: python, regex

From a binary file I've to extract all file names (dll names) in it. I tried following Reg-Ex.

```
 res = re.findall(r'\w+\.dll',dll_content)
```

But its ignoring all dll names which has dash (-) in it, for example 'api-ms-win-security-lsalookup-l2-1-1.dll'. I'm only getting '1.dll'.

What would be the full proof Reg-Ex which will be able to find out all possible dll/file names.

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Word characters" (`\w`) only include

- 'a' through 'z',
- 'A' through 'Z',
- '0' through '9', and
- '_' (underscore)

so if you use

```
\w+\.dll
```

the dashes won't match. You need to use something more like this:

```
[\w-]+\.dll
```

(assuming that the filenames will never have spaces in them).